# How to Create an Interactive Google Spreadsheet for a Soccer Tournament. Linked to Google Forms

Tags: google-sheets

I started making a table for my football tournament, but there is a problem with the automatic calculation of results.

Hello everyone, I started making a table for my football tournament, but there is a problem with the automatic calculation of results.
First, a form was made with which I take out:

- home team name
- name of the visiting team
- home team goals
- away team goals

The problem is that I need to create a standard table in football (socket) with the criteria:
Place, team name, Games, Wins, Draws, Losses, Goals scored, goals missed, Goal difference, points

Please tell me what formula I need to insert so that I can accurately get each of these parameters (regardless of the name of the command)

This is what the data looks like from where I get the results:

| home team name | home team goals | away team goals | name of the visiting team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| team a | 1 | 8 | team b |
| team b | 4 | 3 | team c |
| team b | 3 | 3 | team d |
| team d | 12 | 1 | team a |
| team e | 12 | 2 | team a |
| team c | 13 | 4 | team d |

For my convenience, you can write formulas in this format

1. column B name of the teams in the final table
2. column L Home team
3. column M Goli command at home
4. column N Goals of the visiting team
5. column O Command on the way

=COUNTIFS(L$4:L; B5; M$4:M; ">"&N$4:N) + COUNTIFS(O$4:O; B5; M$4:M; "<"&N$4:N)

I wrote such a formula, but it doesn’t work properly, and now I don’t know how to make it work properly

[My Sheet in my native language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S79no.png)

[Ukrainian Premier League table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqfVD.png)

I want to make something similar to the second picture

Comment: Show your desired output from your given sample.

Comment: table in my native language. I think you will understand

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to calculate

the number of games: =COUNTIFS($L$4:$O;B5)

for winning matches, I used this formula: =SUMPRODUCT((L$4:L = B5) * (M$4:M > N$4:N)) + SUMPRODUCT((O$4:O = B5) * (M$4:M < N$4:N))

for draws, this one: =SUMPRODUCT((L$4:L = B5) * (M$4:M = N$4:N)) + SUMPRODUCT((O$4:O = B5) * (M$4:M = N$4:N))

for losses this one: =SUMPRODUCT((L$4:L = B5) * (M$4:M < N$4:N)) + SUMPRODUCT((O$4:O = B5) * (M$4:M > N$4:N))

for goals scored: =SUMIFS($M$4:$M;$L$4:$L;B5) + SUMIFS($N$4:$N; $O$4:$O; B5)

for the number of goals conceded: =SUMIFS($N$4:$N; $L$4:$L; B5) + SUMIFS($M$4:$M; $O$4:$O; B5)

for goal difference / goals conceded: =G5-H5

for scoring: =D5*3+E5*1

[Screenshot of my table in native language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCq8A.png)